# Show that for every aperiodic state $i$ there exists $n_0$ such that $ p_{ii}^{(n)}>0$ for every $n\geqslant n_0$

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> > Let $(X_n)$ be a Markov chain with state space E. 
> >     Show: If a state $i$ is aperiodic then there exists a $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $p_{ii}^{(n)}>0~\forall~n\geqslant n_0$.

I know that $i\in E$ aperiodic means, that $p(i)=gcd\left\{n>0: p_{ii}^{(n)}>0\right\}=1$.

Could you please show me how I can prove the above statement?

Comment: The intensity of your appreciation of the answer below is really heartwarming.

Comment: Note for future readers, this question could be improved into a full characterization. The reciprocal follows at once, formally I think of the argument to prove that the are infinitely many primes to show that one can always take two arbitrarily large numbers with $gcd = 1$, just take $p_1\ldots p_n +1, p_1 \ldots p_n$

Comment: @Javier What would be the full characterization you have in mind?

Comment: @Did a state i is aperiodic by definition iff $d_i = gcd\{n:p_{ii}^n > 0\} = 1$ this can be shown to be equivalent to $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}.\forall n' \ge n.p_{ii}^{n} > 0$. The hard part is what you did the other implication is trivial and can be thought with my comment above. I think an edition of the question would make it easier to find from the outside

Comment: @Javier But this does not provide the full set $\{n\in\mathbb N\mid p_{ii}^{(n)}\ne0\}$ (I thought you were pointing at this set, hence my first comment).

Answer (score 3):

Once again, this is textbook stuff:

Let $D(i)=\{n\geqslant1\mid p_{ii}^{(n)}\ne0\}$, then, by hypothesis, the greatest common divisor of $D(i)$ is $1$. By Bezout identity, there exists finitely many integers $(n_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant N}$ in $D(i)$ and some integers $(a_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant N}$ such that $$a_1n_1+\cdots+a_Nn_N=1.$$ Assume without loss of generality that $a_k$ is positive for every $k\leqslant M$ and negative otherwise, then the positive integer $$K=|a_{M+1}|n_{M+1}+\cdots+|a_N|n_N,$$ is such that $$K+1=a_1n_1+\cdots+a_Mn_M.$$ Now, the set $D(i)$ is stable by sums and $D(i)$ contains every $n_k$ hence $D(i)$ contains $K$ and $K+1$.

By Euclidean division, each integer $n\geqslant K(K-1)$ can be written as $n=qK+r$ for some nonnegative integers $(q,r)$ such that $q\geqslant K-1\geqslant r$ hence $$n=qK+r(K+1-K)=(q-r)K+r(K+1).$$ Since $q-r$ and $r$ are nonnegative, $K$ and $K+1$ are in $D(i)$, and $D(i)$ is stable by sums, this proves that $D(i)$ contains $n$, thus, $D(i)\supseteq\mathbb N\cap[K(K-1),+\infty)$.